# Laravel get more data in select list

Tags: php, mysql, forms, list, laravel

I am making a select list of my users, but my user are stored in my database with a lastname and firstname. And all the documentation on lists use only one column item from te database. How do I get both these names in my list?

Controller

```
public function make() {
    $users = User::lists('lastname','id');
    return View::make('admin.awardAchievement')->with('users', $users);
}
```

View

```
{{ Form::select('user', $users , Input::old('user')) }}
```

This wil only print out the lastname of my users, but I want the list to show the firstname and lastname.. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using a custom DB expression and concatenate lastname + id. This because the Form helper only likes 1 column for the text (option text) and 1 column for the id (option value attribute).

```
$users = User::select(DB::raw('CONCAT(lastname, id) AS userselect, id'))->lists('userselect', 'id');
```

I find this the way to go, except you have to keep in mind that CONCAT can behave differently on different DBMS's or this function could not even exist. If you do care about this, I would just loop through your users list and manually concatenate with standard PHP script.

Another option is to just adjust the Form helper to support your needs. Though I would not recommend doing this if you want to keep your code rapidly upgradable.

**EDIT: Check first comment**

Comment: Check http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators for defining custom attributes to your model. This would be the best way.

Comment: How would one add a Where clause to your query?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a setter to your model, so something like:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['firstname'] . ' ' . $this->attributes['lastname'];
}
```

and then you can just do

```
$users = User::lists('fullname','id');
```